# how to animate when string interpolation value is changed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation

I have one parent component and child component. I pass value to child component from parent component using @Input(). Now when value will changed from parent , child component will get changed value.

**My question** is when Input() changed , How to animation those value.

**parent-component**

```
<div>
   <child [totalPrice] = "price" />
</div>
```

**child-component**

```
<div>
   {{ totalPrice }}
</div>
```

Now, Value in `{{ totalPrice }}` is changed from parent, and for each changed I wants to animate over screen for indication that something has changed from previous state. How can I do this in angular?

**EDIT**

Demo on this [Stackblitz LInk](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i18y2d?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftotal-price%2Ftotal-price.component.ts)

above I applied angular animation `:enter` and `:leave`. But it works only first time when we selects check-box first time. Second time when value changes, animation is not working.

Comment: Call the animation in https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges lifecycle hook

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm that animation is working only when elements are recreated not when value is changed? I applied animation:[] in component and then in component [@animate] but it will not work when value is changed.

Comment: You could make the input a getter/setter and set some variable that triggers the animation as a sideeffect. Then reset the variable in animation done. (Animation needs to be single direction state change.)

Comment: @GunnarB. see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i18y2d?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftotal-price%2Ftotal-price.component.ts link. I am applying angular-animation. here animation works only first time. second time when value changed animation is not applying.

Comment: You want the whole box with the price to fade out after a while? Should it 'overwrite' an existing box when a change happens before it faded out from the previous (meaning hide instantly and do a new fade in)?

Comment: @GunnerB I simply wants to animate when state changes. Likes when checkbox checked and value updates with animation. Its fadeIn() each value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddled a bit with your stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2atj3s?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftotal-price%2Ftotal-price.component.html

I have a control boolean that I set on value change (the `Input` will only fire on distinct changes). I reset it with a slight timeout upon fade in done (`@myTrigger.done` with stateFrom : stateTo check). Still rough, but generally works.

(If you want something like a checkbox as the input, you should probably make them exclusive.)